# Running tests as part of Docker build in ASP.NET Core

Tags: docker, unit-testing, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm trying to run unit tests as part of the `docker build` process, and I stumbled upon two resources:

- [.NET Core Multi-Stage Dockerfile with Test and Code Coverage in Azure Pipelines](https://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/net-core-multi-stage-dockerfile-with-test-and-code-coverage-in-azure-pipelines)
- [Running .NET Core Unit Tests with Docker and Azure Pipelines](https://blog.ehn.nu/2019/01/running-net-core-unit-tests-with-docker-and-azure-pipelines/) (referenced by the first one).

Basically, if I understand correctly, the gist of what they suggest is to have something like this to run the tests as part of building the final docker image:

```
# First stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
LABEL test=true
# Copy files
RUN dotnet test <project-or-solution> --logger trx --results-directory /test-results
# publish the app etc.

# Second stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
COPY --from=build-env ...
```

And then, in your pipeline (for example, Azure Pipelines), you do something like this to copy the contents of `/test-results` from the first stage (and later publish the results):

```sh
id=$( docker image ls --filter=label=test=true -q | head -n1 )
docker create --name test-container $id
docker cp test-container:/test-results ./test-results
docker rm test-container
```

But, here's what's been happening for me: if one or more tests fail, when I create my `test-container`, the directory `/test-results` is not there; I think the reason is that because the tests are failing in the intermediate container responsible for running tests, the whole Docker build fails, and because of that, the changes in that intermediate container are not committed to an image, and it's only upon the success of unit tests that the `/test-results` is available in the image returned by `--filter=label=test=true`

I've also seen [another approach](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/800f7abd19e230bb215dc63c4983a4c77a1d9e0a/samples/dotnetapp/Dockerfile#L18) where a separate image with an `ENTRYPOINT` is created to be able to run the tests.

What's the proper and recommended way to run C# unit tests in `docker`?

Comment: Well, the simple issue is that docker expects all code commands to return 0 for build process. So you could, in theory, wrap `dotnet test` in something like bash script that will always return 0. However, typically the design is that the build should fail if the tests failed. When i did this, i just had the tests run on the CI, and the docker build was a subsequent step in the build pipeline. you could, i guess, run tests in a separate docker container you create, too.

Comment: Thank you @zaitsman for the reply, I agree with you, seems like a chicken and egg problem here :), but yes, I'm trying to see if I can use a separate container to run the tests

Comment: Have you taken a look here: https://weekly-geekly.github.io/articles/430958/index.html